# Calling a jQuery function multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, ready

So, I have this function in jQuery:

```
$(function(){ 
$( ".unfocused" ).click(function ClickHeader () {
    $( this ).addClass( "focused" );
    $( this ).removeClass( "unfocused" );
    $(".header").not(this).addClass( "unfocused" );
    $(".header").not(this).removeClass( "focused" );
});
});
```

It works perfectly when a header is clicked **the first time**, but when I try to click another unfocused header, the function doesn't work anymore. Is it because it runs on document .ready?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: delegate event in order to get it works for new .unfocused elements (with unfocused class added) and btw no more for old ones (class removed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it like this:

```
  $( document ).on("click", ".unfocused", function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "focused" );
    $( this ).removeClass( "unfocused" );
    $(".header").not(this).addClass( "unfocused" );
    $(".header").not(this).removeClass( "focused" );
  });
```

This basically registers the event on the document. When you click a header, the event bubbles up to the document. There, the given selector is validated and the function is executed if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsfiddle using the delegate operation for handling the event like you need.

http://jsfiddle.net/MN9Zt/2/

```
$("body").delegate(".unfocused", "click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("focused");
    $(this).removeClass("unfocused");
    $(".header").not(this).addClass("unfocused");
    $(".header").not(this).removeClass("focused");
});
```

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.` Still valid code, though.

Comment: Totally awesome! Works like a charm. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol thanks for the comment! I always forget which one is the best to use. About all I can remember is "live" is "dead" (deprecated)