# How to fix clicking functionality with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the javascript/html below.  When the user clicks on 'heart' or 'coal' it switches to the opposite.  However, it only works for 1 click.  If I click on 'heart' once, it turns into 'coal'...but if I click on 'coal' now, it doesn't turn into 'heart' again.  Any idea on how to fix this?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.like').click(function (e) {
            $(this).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>");
            console.log('liked');
            return false;            
        })

        $('.unlike').click(function (e) {
            $(this).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'like'><div class = 'coal'></div></a>");
            console.log('unliked');
            return false;            
        })
    })
 </script>


                       <div>
                    <a href = "#" class = 'unlike'>
                        <div class = "heart"></div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
```

Comment: See this answer for more information about why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035746/calling-a-jquery-function-multiple-times/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@meavo is correct.

Here is a sample jsfiddle with a code sample similar to what you posted.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q2pDG/

```
$(document).on("click", '.like', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'unlike'><div class = 'heart'></div></a>");
    return false;
});

$(document).on("click", '.unlike', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().html("<a href = '#' class = 'like'><div class = 'coal'></div></a>");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$('body').on('click', '.like', function () {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is because you are adding dynamically an element (by destroying and recreating it), and the new element have no event click handler bound to it.

The solution is the use of event delegation, you can use jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Another solution is instead of create again and again the clicked element, add a generic class, and in its click change the inner HTML and switch the like/unlike classes.

Code:

```
<div> <a href="#" class='handler unlike'>
    <div class = "heart">aa</div>
</a></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.handler').click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('like')) {
            $(this).html("<div class = 'heart'>aa</div>");
        } else {
            $(this).html("<div class = 'coal'>bb</div>");
        }

        $(this).toggleClass('unlike');
        $(this).toggleClass('like');
        return false;
    })

})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/At3D9/