# jQuery update input field multiple times

Tags: jquery, input

I'm currently using the following to update an input field without reloading the entire page:

```
<input type="number" name="voorraad" id="5258" class="voorraad 5258" value="129">

<script>
(function($) {
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.voorraad').blur(function(){

var nieuwevoorraad = jQuery(this).val();
var productid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
jQuery( "." + productid ).replaceWith( '<span class="' + productid + '_glyphspan"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span> Bijwerken...</span>' );
    $.post("<?php echo site_url();?>/updateStock.php",{
        productid : productid,
        nieuwevoorraad : nieuwevoorraad,

     },

  function(result){
  jQuery( "." + productid + "_glyphspan" ).replaceWith( '<input type="number" name="voorraad" id="'+productid+'" class="voorraad '+productid+'" value="'+nieuwevoorraad+'"/>' );
        });
});
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

However, after the second replace, the input field no longer works, and I need to refresh the entire page. What I am looking for, is that the script runs on each change I make to the input field. Any ideas?

Comment: What about `.change` event?

Comment: Could you possibly add some relevant `html` code too?

Comment: please provide your HTML code also

Comment: HTML added. Already tried .change but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace

```
jQuery('.voorraad').blur(function(){
```

with

```
jQuery(document).on("blur",".voorraad",function(){
```

because you dynamically replace this element.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this did the trick

```
<script>
(function($) {

jQuery( document ).on("blur", ".voorraad", function() {


var nieuwevoorraad = jQuery(this).val();
var productid = jQuery(this).attr('id');
jQuery( "." + productid ).replaceWith( '<span class="' + productid + '_glyphspan"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span> Bijwerken...</span>' );
    $.post("<?php echo site_url();?>/updateStock.php",{
        productid : productid,
        nieuwevoorraad : nieuwevoorraad,

     },

  function(result){
  jQuery( "." + productid + "_glyphspan" ).replaceWith( '<input type="number" name="voorraad" id="'+productid+'" class="voorraad '+productid+'" value="'+nieuwevoorraad+'"/>' );
        });
});

})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Found here: [Calling a jQuery function multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035746/calling-a-jquery-function-multiple-times)